# How to make reopen websocket connection in Vuex after page refresh?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

After user has registered to my app, one component sends an action to Vuex to start listening to update requests from the server using Websocket.

Vuex action:

```
  const socket = io(url);
  socket.on(id, data => {
     ...
```

I'm using Vuex-persisted to use LocalStorage for storing state. However, if user refreshes the browser, the websocket connection is lost. If I include the socket into Vuex state, I get the following error:

```
vuex-persistedstate.es.js?0e44:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Socket'
    |     property 'io' -> object with constructor 'Manager'
    |     property 'nsps' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    --- property '/' closes the circle
```

Since there are no lifecycle hooks for Vuex, how can I resume the websocket connection after refresh?

Also Vuex should refresh the state from backend always after refresh, to be sure that no update request event was lost while the websocket connection was down.

Comment: Are you sure that this is the best practice to listen to the update request in the Vuex?
Maybe you should do it in the `mounted()` hook of the component? And fire the action in the Vuex then the data is fetched.

Comment: @Justice47 There are several components who need this data, so it seems redundant to fire the websocket in each of the mounted hooks - but of course I have to do it if it's the only possibility.

Comment: In my opinion there is no need to fire up websocket connection in every component. You can fetch data only in one component, write it in the Vuex store and than use getters to make it accessible in other components

Comment: @Justice47 then I would need to have one parent object handling the socket for all children, right?

Comment: if you will write any value from socket to Vuex the inheritance of components doesn't matter - the one will handle the socket and write to Vuex and all other will be using `getter`